# Como habilito o upload de arquivos grandes no ASP clássico no IIS?

Tags: asp.net, asp

Tenho um sistema de upload em ASP Clássico. Consigo fazer upload de até 200KB sem problemas, mas quanto tento um tamanho maior ocorre o erro:

Request object error 'ASP 0104 : 80004005'
Operation not Allowed
/admin/freeaspupload.asp, line 101

Vi que preciso ajustar o arquivo web.config no servidor de hospedagem (godaddy), então coloquei da forma abaixo, mas mesmo assim o erro continua.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.web>
<customErrors mode="Off"/>    
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647"/>
<sessionState timeout="1600"  />
</system.web>
    
<system.webServer>
    <httpRedirect enabled="false" destination="" exactDestination="true" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed">
<remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
<remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
</httpErrors>
    <security>
<requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647"/>
</requestFiltering>
</security>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Alguém para me ajudar por favor?

Answer (score 1):

Ricardo, coloquei da forma que repassou, mas da erro novamente

HTTP/1.1 New Application Failed

Pesquisei a respeito e é muito vago o problema. :Imagino que seja pelo  que não está aceitando. Algo referente ao IIS 8.5

Answer (score 0):

Apesar ser "ASP clássico", por conta da página "freeaspupload.asp", esse config é do ASP.Net.

Precisa incluir nele uma section `<asp>` com as configurações dentro do `<system.webServer>`, definindo "maxRequestEntityAllowed", e como o file é grande e pode demorar, o "scriptTimeout" também:

```
<system.webServer>
  <asp>
     <limits scriptTimeout="00:01:00"
        requestQueueMax="1000"
        maxRequestEntityAllowed="104857600" />
  </asp>
  ... outras settings
</system.webServer>
```